# How to empty input value that already auto pick value from timepicker when screen load?

Tags: javascript

How to empty the timepicker value input that auto display when load the page? The problem is because when i submit the form, it will send it all.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById('sundayFrom_Box').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('sundayFrom').disabled = !this.checked;
    document.getElementById('sundayTo').disabled = !this.checked;
    $("#sundayFrom").val(null);
    $("#sundayTo").val(null);
    };
});
```

```
<input type="checkbox" id="sundayFrom_Box"/>
<input id="sundayFrom" type="text" class="form-control timepicker timepicker-no-seconds" name="sundayFrom">
<input id="sundayTo" type="text" class="form-control timepicker timepicker-no-seconds" name="sundayTo">
```

[image: screemshot]

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="sundayFrom_Box" checked/>

Comment: The disabled controls will not be submitted with the form. You code should work.

Comment: Maybe try $("#sundayFrom").html(''); instea of val(null) :).
And you can put it to setTimeout(function(){},300) to make sure that timepicker wont overwrite it.

Comment: Racil Hilan, yup its work if disable.sorry i forgot to mention in my question. but i want change to empty value so i don need use the checkbox function anymore , because right now, user need to uncheck the checkbox if they don want.How about if user want sunday only so the user need to uncheck the other 6 checkbox. and my updated code is <input type="checkbox" id="sundayFrom_Box" checked/>.

Answer (score 0):

Is this Bootstrap Timepicker? Per the docs (https://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/) set the defaultTime property to false so it doesn't initialize with a default value.